# How can we use Mozilla to Screen Scrape raw data from real estate listings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm looking at this URL.

https://www.century21.com/real-estate/long-island-city-ny/LCNYLONGISLANDCITY/

I'm trying to get this text, in a structured format.

```
FOR SALE
$1,248,000
3 beds
2 baths
45-09 Skillman Avenue
Sunnyside NY 11104
Listed By CENTURY 21 Sunny Gardens Realty, Inc.

##########################################


FOR SALE
$1,390,000
5 beds
3 baths
2,200 sq. ft
47-35 39th Place
Sunnyside NY 11104
Courtesy Of Keller Williams Realty of Greater Nassau
```

[image]

Here's the sample code that i tried to hack together.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep


url='https://www.century21.com/real-estate/long-island-city-ny/LCNYLONGISLANDCITY/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Utility\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
sleep(3)


content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features='html.parser')
for element in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'infinite-item property-card clearfix property-card-C2183089596 initialized visited'}):
   #print(element)
   address = element.find('div', attrs={'class': 'property-card-primary-info'})
   print(address)
   price = element.find('a', attrs={'class': 'listing-price'})
   print(price)
```

When I run this, I get no addresses and no prices. Not sure why.

Comment: *"does this require a totally different approach?"*: Yes. You've written this as if you were interacting with a nice clean API that returns some data in JSON format. Instead you are wanting to scrape HTML from a website. Best to use a module like beautifulsoup, selenium, or scrapy for this job so you can read in the DOM and navigate with code.

Comment: I'm trying BeautifulSoup now. The code runs, but it doesn't print any addresses and it doesn't print any prices. Not sure what's wrong, but something is not setup right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web scraping is more of an art than a science. It's helpful to pull up the page source in chrome or browser of your choice so you can think about the DOM hierarchy and figure out how to get down into the elements that you need to scrape. Some websites have been built very cleanly and this isn't too much work, and others are scrapped together nonsense that are nightmares to dig data out of it.

This one, thankfully, is very clean.

This isn't perfect, but I think it will get you in the ballpark:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url='https://www.century21.com/real-estate/long-island-city-ny/LCNYLONGISLANDCITY/'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features='html.parser')
for element in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'property-card'}):    
    address = element.find('div', attrs={'class': 'property-card-primary-info'}).find('div', attrs={'class': 'property-address-info'})
    for address_item in address.children:
        print(address_item.get_text().strip())
    price = element.find('div',attrs={'class': 'property-card-primary-info'}).find('a', attrs={'class': 'listing-price'})
    print(price.get_text().strip())
```

Comment: This makes more sense than the way I tried to do it. Thanks for sharing!!